# Remove element's class using only JavaScript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get an element by class name, and after, remove it's class.

I wish to accomplish that using JavaScript only, no jQuery.

Here is what I've tried already:

```
<script>
  var changeController = function() {
    var removeClass = document.getElementsByClassName("selected-hr")[0];
    removeClass.classList.remove("selected-hr");
  }
</script>

<div class="col col-25 selected-hr">
  <a class="tb-header-link" onclick="changeController()">ALL</a>
</div>
```

EDIT 1:
Fixed typo at `changeController()`

Comment: `onclick="changeController()"`

Comment: This works for me without any problem.

Comment: `onclick="return changeController();" ` professionalism..

Comment: code working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `this` into `changeController()`, use `parentNode` property to reference the div. Place the `<script>` after the your markup (HTML) to ensure DOM is loaded before running script. Preferably before the `</body>` closing tag.

### Snippet

```css
a {text-decoration:none;}
.selected-hr {background:tomato;}
```

```html
<div class="col col-25 selected-hr">
  <a href='#/' class="tb-header-link" onclick="changeController(this)">ALL</a>
</div>

<script>
  function changeController(ele) {
    var parent = ele.parentNode;
    parent.classList.remove("selected-hr");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just mentioning the name of a variable does nothing (even if the variable points to a function).

You have to call it if you want to do anything with it. Add `()`.

```
onclick="changeController()"
```

Comment: Ok, that was a typo. I already fixed it, but the code is still not working.

Comment: @GreetingsFriend — Given that fix, it works for me: http://jsbin.com/tubuduh/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I just checked the console. changeController is not defined. The script is on a nested view just on top of the html(using angular-ui router). Where should i place the script?